# Connect models together with Keras

Tags: machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, model, functional-programming

I have this Unet model from python library "segmentation_models", this model is a Functional model from Keras :

```py
unet_vgg16 = Unet('vgg16', classes=NUM_CLASSES, encoder_weights='imagenet', input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3), encoder_freeze=True)
```

And I have a data augmentation model :

```py
data_augm_inputs = layers.Input(shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3))
flip = layers.RandomFlip("horizontal_and_vertical")(data_augm_inputs)
rotation = layers.RandomRotation(0.2)(flip)
zoom = layers.RandomZoom(.5)(rotation)

data_augmentation = Model(inputs=data_augm_inputs, outputs=zoom)
```

I want to connect to the top my data augmentation model to my Unet model :

```py
final = Model(inputs=data_augm_inputs, outputs=unet_vgg16.output)
```

But I have this error :

ValueError: Graph disconnected: cannot obtain value for tensor KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 512, 512, 3), dtype=tf.float32, name='input_12'), name='input_12', description="created by layer 'input_12'") at layer "block1_conv1". The following previous layers were accessed without issue: []

My unet model summary :

```
Model: "model_18"
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape                 Param #   Connected to                  
==================================================================================================
 input_12 (InputLayer)       [(None, 512, 512, 3)]        0         []                            
                                                                                                  
 block1_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 512, 512, 64)         1792      ['input_12[0][0]']            
                                                                                                  
 block1_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 512, 512, 64)         36928     ['block1_conv1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 256, 256, 64)         0         ['block1_conv2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block2_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 256, 256, 128)        73856     ['block1_pool[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 block2_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 256, 256, 128)        147584    ['block2_conv1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 128, 128, 128)        0         ['block2_conv2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block3_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 128, 128, 256)        295168    ['block2_pool[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 block3_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 128, 128, 256)        590080    ['block3_conv1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block3_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 128, 128, 256)        590080    ['block3_conv2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 64, 64, 256)          0         ['block3_conv3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block4_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 64, 512)          1180160   ['block3_pool[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 block4_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 64, 512)          2359808   ['block4_conv1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block4_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 64, 64, 512)          2359808   ['block4_conv2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 32, 32, 512)          0         ['block4_conv3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block5_conv1 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 32, 512)          2359808   ['block4_pool[0][0]']         
                                                                                                  
 block5_conv2 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 32, 512)          2359808   ['block5_conv1[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block5_conv3 (Conv2D)       (None, 32, 32, 512)          2359808   ['block5_conv2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)  (None, 16, 16, 512)          0         ['block5_conv3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 center_block1_conv (Conv2D  (None, 16, 16, 512)          2359296   ['block5_pool[0][0]']         
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 center_block1_bn (BatchNor  (None, 16, 16, 512)          2048      ['center_block1_conv[0][0]']  
 malization)                                                                                      
                                                                                                  
 center_block1_relu (Activa  (None, 16, 16, 512)          0         ['center_block1_bn[0][0]']    
 tion)                                                                                            
                                                                                                  
 center_block2_conv (Conv2D  (None, 16, 16, 512)          2359296   ['center_block1_relu[0][0]']  
 )                                                                                                
                                                                                                  
 center_block2_bn (BatchNor  (None, 16, 16, 512)          2048      ['center_block2_conv[0][0]']  
 malization)                                                                                      
                                                                                                  
 center_block2_relu (Activa  (None, 16, 16, 512)          0         ['center_block2_bn[0][0]']    
 tion)                                                                                            
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage0_upsampling   (None, 32, 32, 512)          0         ['center_block2_relu[0][0]']  
 (UpSampling2D)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage0_concat (Con  (None, 32, 32, 1024)         0         ['decoder_stage0_upsampling[0]
 catenate)                                                          [0]',                         
                                                                     'block5_conv3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage0a_conv (Conv  (None, 32, 32, 256)          2359296   ['decoder_stage0_concat[0][0]'
 2D)                                                                ]                             
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage0a_bn (BatchN  (None, 32, 32, 256)          1024      ['decoder_stage0a_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage0a_relu (Acti  (None, 32, 32, 256)          0         ['decoder_stage0a_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage0b_conv (Conv  (None, 32, 32, 256)          589824    ['decoder_stage0a_relu[0][0]']
 2D)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage0b_bn (BatchN  (None, 32, 32, 256)          1024      ['decoder_stage0b_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage0b_relu (Acti  (None, 32, 32, 256)          0         ['decoder_stage0b_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage1_upsampling   (None, 64, 64, 256)          0         ['decoder_stage0b_relu[0][0]']
 (UpSampling2D)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage1_concat (Con  (None, 64, 64, 768)          0         ['decoder_stage1_upsampling[0]
 catenate)                                                          [0]',                         
                                                                     'block4_conv3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage1a_conv (Conv  (None, 64, 64, 128)          884736    ['decoder_stage1_concat[0][0]'
 2D)                                                                ]                             
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage1a_bn (BatchN  (None, 64, 64, 128)          512       ['decoder_stage1a_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage1a_relu (Acti  (None, 64, 64, 128)          0         ['decoder_stage1a_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage1b_conv (Conv  (None, 64, 64, 128)          147456    ['decoder_stage1a_relu[0][0]']
 2D)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage1b_bn (BatchN  (None, 64, 64, 128)          512       ['decoder_stage1b_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage1b_relu (Acti  (None, 64, 64, 128)          0         ['decoder_stage1b_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage2_upsampling   (None, 128, 128, 128)        0         ['decoder_stage1b_relu[0][0]']
 (UpSampling2D)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage2_concat (Con  (None, 128, 128, 384)        0         ['decoder_stage2_upsampling[0]
 catenate)                                                          [0]',                         
                                                                     'block3_conv3[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage2a_conv (Conv  (None, 128, 128, 64)         221184    ['decoder_stage2_concat[0][0]'
 2D)                                                                ]                             
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage2a_bn (BatchN  (None, 128, 128, 64)         256       ['decoder_stage2a_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage2a_relu (Acti  (None, 128, 128, 64)         0         ['decoder_stage2a_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage2b_conv (Conv  (None, 128, 128, 64)         36864     ['decoder_stage2a_relu[0][0]']
 2D)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage2b_bn (BatchN  (None, 128, 128, 64)         256       ['decoder_stage2b_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage2b_relu (Acti  (None, 128, 128, 64)         0         ['decoder_stage2b_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage3_upsampling   (None, 256, 256, 64)         0         ['decoder_stage2b_relu[0][0]']
 (UpSampling2D)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage3_concat (Con  (None, 256, 256, 192)        0         ['decoder_stage3_upsampling[0]
 catenate)                                                          [0]',                         
                                                                     'block2_conv2[0][0]']        
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage3a_conv (Conv  (None, 256, 256, 32)         55296     ['decoder_stage3_concat[0][0]'
 2D)                                                                ]                             
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage3a_bn (BatchN  (None, 256, 256, 32)         128       ['decoder_stage3a_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage3a_relu (Acti  (None, 256, 256, 32)         0         ['decoder_stage3a_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage3b_conv (Conv  (None, 256, 256, 32)         9216      ['decoder_stage3a_relu[0][0]']
 2D)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage3b_bn (BatchN  (None, 256, 256, 32)         128       ['decoder_stage3b_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage3b_relu (Acti  (None, 256, 256, 32)         0         ['decoder_stage3b_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage4_upsampling   (None, 512, 512, 32)         0         ['decoder_stage3b_relu[0][0]']
 (UpSampling2D)                                                                                   
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage4a_conv (Conv  (None, 512, 512, 16)         4608      ['decoder_stage4_upsampling[0]
 2D)                                                                [0]']                         
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage4a_bn (BatchN  (None, 512, 512, 16)         64        ['decoder_stage4a_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage4a_relu (Acti  (None, 512, 512, 16)         0         ['decoder_stage4a_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage4b_conv (Conv  (None, 512, 512, 16)         2304      ['decoder_stage4a_relu[0][0]']
 2D)                                                                                              
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage4b_bn (BatchN  (None, 512, 512, 16)         64        ['decoder_stage4b_conv[0][0]']
 ormalization)                                                                                    
                                                                                                  
 decoder_stage4b_relu (Acti  (None, 512, 512, 16)         0         ['decoder_stage4b_bn[0][0]']  
 vation)                                                                                          
                                                                                                  
 final_conv (Conv2D)         (None, 512, 512, 8)          1160      ['decoder_stage4b_relu[0][0]']
                                                                                                  
 sigmoid (Activation)        (None, 512, 512, 8)          0         ['final_conv[0][0]']          
                                                                                                  
==================================================================================================
Total params: 23753288 (90.61 MB)
Trainable params: 9034568 (34.46 MB)
Non-trainable params: 14718720 (56.15 MB)
```

and my data augmentation model summary :

```
Model: "model_15"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 input_11 (InputLayer)       [(None, 512, 512, 3)]     0         
                                                                 
 random_flip_2 (RandomFlip)  (None, 512, 512, 3)       0         
                                                                 
 random_rotation_2 (RandomR  (None, 512, 512, 3)       0         
 otation)                                                        
                                                                 
 random_zoom_2 (RandomZoom)  (None, 512, 512, 3)       0         
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
Trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_________________________________________________________________
```

I don't understand and I'm little confused.
How to connect this 2 models?

Comment: IMAGE_SIZE = 512

Comment: from keras.models import Model
from keras import layers

from segmentation_models import Unet

IMAGE_SIZE = 512

Keras version => 2.15.0